# failed to execute appendchild on node

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying create a new tr in my table

js:

```
function addElement() {

    var message = document.getElementById('inputsend');
    var now = new Date();

    var table = document.getElementById('messagebox');

    var tr = document.createElement('tr');

    var tdTime = document.createElement('td');
    tdTime.innerHTML = now.getHours() +":"+now.getMinutes() + " ";

    var tdName = document.createElement('td');
    tdName = userName + " ";

    var tdMessage = document.createElement('td');
    tdMessage = message;

    tr.appendChild(tdTime);
    tr.appendChild(tdName);
    tr.appendChild(tdMessage);

    table.appendChild(tr);

    document.getElementById('inputsend').value = "";

}
```

html:

```
<table id="messagebox">
</table>
```

but its dont work and chrome say failed to execute appendchild on node

Comment: fixed
 tdName.innerHTML = userName + " ";

var tdMessage.innerHTML = document.createElement('td');
tdMessage.innerHTML = message.value;

Comment: I just noticed your comment after posting the answer. You should post it as an answer and accept it as the solution, so people don't open this post trying to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.innerHTML` is missing from `tdName` & `tdMessage`, so you're passing a string to `appendChild` which it can't handle.

```
var tdName = document.createElement('td');
tdName.innerHTML = userName + " ";

var tdMessage = document.createElement('td');
tdMessage.innerHTML = message;
```